# synchronize mysql database table from csv file on intervals

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to update mysql database table from .txt file which have comma seperated values.
I know there is a way to update mysql table from csv file but what extra i want is that to update or synchronize that txt file with the mysql table every hour or any defined time.

May be that is possible with events, but i am not sure how i can keep the txt file synchronize with the database table.

i have this csv .txt file like this..

```
9048,Ms,Rebecca,Self,DUE OUT,5070547,5209592,21.09.14,26.09.14,PM,1,,
9049,Ms,Zeynep,Yalnizbagli,CHECKED IN,5158298,5296557,23.09.14,27.09.14,PM,0,9013,
9050,Mr.,Mohamed,Jannan,CHECKED IN,5119066,5258076,21.09.14,27.09.14,PM,1,,
9050,Mr.,Roy,Sfeir,CHECKED IN,5031794,5170810,07.09.14,27.09.14,PM,1,1304,
9300,,,POS- Cash,CHECKED IN,5081300,5221061,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9300,
9300,,,POS- Cash,CHECKED IN,5081300,5221061,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9300,
9303,,,POS - AMEX,CHECKED IN,5081295,5221056,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9303,
9304,,,POS - VISA,CHECKED IN,5081299,5221060,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9304,
9305,,,POS - Master,CHECKED IN,5081298,5221059,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9305,
9306,,,POS - Dinners,CHECKED IN,5081296,5221057,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9306,
9310,,,POS - Maestro,CHECKED IN,5081297,5221058,01.09.14,30.09.14,PI,0,9310,
9500,,,Lost Interface,CHECKED IN,5081302,5221063,01.09.14,30.09.14,PM,0,9500,
9501,Mr.,Owning Co.,Al Ajaj Trading and Co,CHECKED IN,5081301,5221062,01.09.14,30.09.14,PM,0,9501,
```

Now Problem is of synchronizing the mysql table from this file on intervals like after each hour or two.

Comment: Write a script and execute it on cron.

Comment: Use MariaDB [Connect Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/connect/)